# Connect Azure in UWP

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have try to fix the code that will get the data of promotion from SQL database on azure (Table name is Promo that consist of id,PromoName,...etc.)

I'm try to use the WCF service by create these code

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<PromotionList> GetPromotionList();

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

Which have effected on the Service1.svc.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<PromotionList> GetPromotionList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<PromotionList> result = new ObservableCollection<PromotionList>();
        //Add data string here
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = //This one is ado one that copy from the azure
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            //Query Here
            String cmdText = "Select * from Promo";
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new PromotionList(){id=dr.GetInt32(0),PromoName=dr.GetString(1)});
            }

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(conn.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

for real the data in promo table have more detail but I'm selected only 2

```
public class PromotionList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string PromoName { get; set; }
}
```

And I use this service to the service reference of my main application and call it

```
(In method public sealed partial class MainPage : Page)

public ObservableCollection<Connector.PromotionList> PromoList { get; set; }
....
(In method public MainPage())
PromoList = new ObservableCollection<Connector.PromotionList>();
....
(In method When the button is click)
 Connector.Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
 PromoList = client.GetPromotionListAsync().Result;
 Debug.WriteLine(PromoList[0].PromoName);
```

It's won't work with exception "The name "InnerExceptionCount" does not exist in current context"

I would like to know why is this exception occurs and how to solved it

Thank you

Comment: Can you share if the exception is coming on your Client App or Web Service?

Comment: When I run application on device it's crash an get exception on "PromoList = client.GetPromotionListAsync().Result;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All errors from wcf service will throw this exception. 
From your code, the connectstring is wrong or the table promo is not existing may occur this error. So check the WCF service code in Service1.svc.cs.
I have tested these code with a right connectionstring and right table, it works well.